# What are nice use cases for cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

It's evident that the [cURL functions](http://php.net/curl) are very widely used. But why is that? Is it really only because the extension is mostly enabled per default?

While I can certainly relate to not introducing 3rd party libraries over builtins (DOMDocument vs phpQuery), using curl appears somewhat odd to me. There are heaps of HTTP libraries like [Zend_Http](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html) or [PEAR Http_Request](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request/). And despite my disdain for needless object-oriented interfaces, the **pull-parameter-procedural API** of curl strikes me as less legible in comparison.

There is of course a reason for that. But I'm wondering if most PHP developers realize **what else libcurl can actually be used for, and that it's not just a HTTP library**?

Do you have examples or actual code which utilizes cURL for <any other things> it was made for?

Or if you just use it for HTTP, what are the reasons. Why are real PHP HTTP libraries seemingly avoided nowadays?

Comment: Ignorance seems the most likely cause.

Comment: curl *used* to be the only thing that could handle cookies, POST, file uploads... A lot of curl use probably comes from tutorials that pre-date PHP 5. You often read SO questions starting with "I heard I need to use curl for this,...."

Comment: This is a rant, not a programming question with a specific answer. Off-topic.

Comment: It's very old, widely used and well tested code, works reliably, is usually enabled by default and allows very fine grained control over the details of the request. Apart from the interface being ugly, there's no real reason to complain about it. If your framework/library of choice doesn't come with a better integrated library, why *not* use it? Also agree with @Dan, this is S&A.

Comment: @deceze: Regarding the closevoting: better opportunities have been missed. If the nomenclature or mentioning of the API are a personal offense to curl aficionados, that text is open for redaction, as usual. It's in no way the crux of the question; it's introduction. And "complain about it" seems to be a cursorily reading.

Comment: @mario No, that's not actually the problem. The problem is that there's no objective, or even just *one* answer for the primary question *"nice use cases for cURL."* And yes, I'm reading *"clumsy … API … strikes me as retarded"* as "complaining". Sosumi. ;o))

Comment: @deceze: Being blunt != not objective. And no, it's not an advisable API scheme by any definition (still looking for the proper terminology though). The question is open ended by leaving the use case mysterious. Unless you know which other things cURL is able to do, it's not answerable with an example or a compound use pattern. It's interesting that nobody inquired about that yet.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be related to why do people use the mysql functions instead of mysqli (more object oriented interface) or take a step further and use a data abstraction layer or PDOs.

HTTP_Request2 says that there is a cURL adapter available to wrap around PHP's cURL functions.

Personally a lot of the PEAR extensions I have tried out, I haven't been that impressed with (and I feel less confident with PEAR libraries that are sitting in alpha that haven't been updated in a long time). Whereas the HTTP_Request2 Library does look quite nice

I for one would have used cURL without thinking of looking at a possible PEAR library to use. So thanks for raising my awareness.

Comment: That seems a very relevant cause. +1 If cURL appears of better quality than e.g. a PEAR implementation (or any other class), then it's a plausible reason to prefer curl.

Comment: You can also specify cURL as the connector for `Zend_Http_Client` instead of the default socket option (why anyone would do this, I couldn't say)

Comment: I guess that reflects a database abstraction layer even more.

Answer (score 1):

The libraries you mentioned aren't default, and from my experience in PHP, I prefer to use less of such libraries; they enable a broader attack surface, decrease reliability, open to future modification/deprecation more than PHP itself.

Then, there's the sockets functionality which, although I've used some times, I prefer to rely on a higher level approach whenever possible.

What have I used CURL for?

As some may know, I'm currently working on a PHP framework. The communication core extension (appropriately called "connect") makes use of CURL as it's base.

I've used it widely, from extracting favicons form websites (together with parser utilities and stuff) to standard API calls over HTTP as well as the FTP layer when PHP's FTP is disabled (through stream wrappers) - and we all know native PHP FTP ain't that reliable.

Comment: That's probably it. The defaultness (not particular features) is what makes curl most attractive? -- The FTP usage is what I was after (need to repurpose the question). Can totally relate to not liking the PHP ftp_ functions. - But did you e.g. ever use HTTP+FTP (alternating) in a single curl utilization block?

Comment: I can't say for sure, you know how frameworks tend to build up; I might eventually be doing it without knowing myself. But I think that CURL strikes the perfect balance between easy-to-use features AND defaultness - the earlier missing in many low-level functionality and latter one missing in PHP extensions.

Comment: well cURL is kind of default, it's popular, but I had to install it for itself. I.e. it's not bundled.

Comment: chelmertz - What's your server situation (hosting provider, server software, PHP version)? I've always found it available on HostGator servers (at least starting with PHP 5). Though I know for sure WAMP on windows has CURL disabled by default (all versions AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

Functional reasons as mentioned in the comments:

- It's very old, [*widely used* and] well tested code, **works reliably**
- is usually enabled by default
- allows very fine grained control over the details of the request.

  - This might need expanding. By nature of the common-denominator protocol API cURL might provide features that plain HTTP libraries in PHP can't...

Historic reasons:

- curl used to be the only thing that could handle cookies, POST, file uploads...
- A lot of curl use probably comes from **tutorials that pre-date PHP 5**.